# what is wrong with Eigen vectors of this matrix?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

given matrix is $$\begin{bmatrix} 2&1\\ 3&2\end{bmatrix}$$
The eigen vectors of this matrix are

A) $\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt 3\\3\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt 3\\-3\end{bmatrix}\qquad$
B) $\begin{bmatrix}i\sqrt 3\\3\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}i\sqrt 3\\-3\end{bmatrix}\qquad $
C) $\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt 3\\3\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}-\sqrt 3\\-3\end{bmatrix}\qquad $
D) $\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt 3\\1\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt 3\\-1\end{bmatrix}\qquad $

my try: assuming $\lambda$ eigen value,
$$\left|\begin{matrix} 2-\lambda & 1\\ 3 & 2-\lambda \end{matrix}\right|=0\implies \lambda= 2\pm\sqrt 3$$
then eigen vectors for $\lambda=2-\sqrt3$ are
$$\begin{bmatrix} \sqrt 3 & 1\\ 3 & \sqrt 3 \end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix} x_1\\ x_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 0\end{bmatrix} $$ 
$$x_1\sqrt3 +x_2=0\ \ or\ \ 3x_1+x_2\sqrt 3=0$$
so eigen vectors are $\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt 3\\1\end{bmatrix}$ or $\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt 3\\3\end{bmatrix}\qquad$

similarly for $\lambda =2+\sqrt 3$, eigen vectors are so vectors are $\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt 3\\-1\end{bmatrix}$ or $\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt 3\\-3\end{bmatrix}\qquad$

i know answer is option A but i don't understand the reason why don't we take  $\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt 3\\1\end{bmatrix}$ & $\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt 3\\-1\end{bmatrix}$ ? please help me. thanks

Comment: oops, i have not shown that step. anyway i have computed eigen values so please give answer to my question

Comment: what do you mean by RREF?

Comment: How are you ending up with two linearly independent choices of eigenvector for each eigenvalue? Only one of them is actually a solution for the equations that you’ve set up.

Comment: The vector $\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt 3\\1\end{bmatrix}$ does not solve the equations $x_1\sqrt3 +x_2=0$ or $3x_1+x_2\sqrt 3=0$. Likewise for the vector $\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt 3\\-1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @Did vector $\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt 3\\3\end{bmatrix}\qquad$ also doesn't satisfy $x_1\sqrt 3+x_2=0$ or $3x_1+x_2\sqrt3=0$ so why do we take vector $\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt 3\\3\end{bmatrix}\qquad$?. then we should only take  vector $\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt 3\\-3\end{bmatrix}\qquad$ because it satisfies both $x_1\sqrt 3+x_2=0$ & $3x_1+x_2\sqrt3=0$

Comment: Yes, but $(\sqrt3,3)^T$ does satisfy $\sqrt3x_1-x_2=0$. Likewise for $(\sqrt3,-3)^T$ and $\sqrt3x_1+x_2=0$. And this is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

From $x_1\sqrt 3 + x_2=0$ you should get that the eigenvector is $\begin {bmatrix}  1\\-\sqrt 3 \end {bmatrix}$  Neither of the vectors you propose satisfiesthe equation.  Similarly, from $-x_1\sqrt 3 + x_2=0$ you should find $\begin {bmatrix}  1\\ \sqrt 3 \end {bmatrix}$.  Multiplying both by $\sqrt 3$ gives the choices in A.  You should only get one eigenvalue per (nondegenerate) eigenvalue.